# Put a command in a variable

Tags: batch-file

I want to store this command in a variable called code1

```
    dir /a:d /b
```

so the output would be:
Folder1
Folder2
Folder3
etc...
Any ideas how to do it?
I've checked other questions and when it just sais echo is off.

Comment: Do you want to store the output in a variable, or do you want to store `dir /a:d /b` as the value of a variable?

Comment: output of the variable so when i do echo %code1% it displays all the folders

Comment: Look at the output of `for /?`, specifically the part about `for /F` loops.

Comment: did look at it and it doesn't work

Comment: _Really?_ `for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir /a:d /b') do echo %%A` didn't work?

Answer (score 3):

Simply store the command in the variable like you say. To execute, simply expand the value:

```
@echo off
setlocal

:: Define a simple "macro"
set "code1=dir /a:d /b"

:: Execute the "macro"
%code1%
```